# How to left-align more than two lines in HTML-like label?

Tags: graphviz

I can successfully left-align the first two lines, but not the third, in an HTML-like label using the following code:

```
digraph TTS {
    node [shape="box"];
    a [label=<line 1 --------<BR ALIGN="LEFT"/>line 2 ----<BR ALIGN="LEFT"/>line 3>];
}
```

The result is this

[image: image with bad alignment]

How can I get this instead?

[image]

Comment: Add another `<BR ALIGN="LEFT"/>` after line 3.

Comment: @bergant That works, thanks. It is much simpler than the workaround I came up with, which was to use `<TABLE>` markup. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another `<BR ALIGN="LEFT"/>` after the "line 3" would align it.

For this case even more simple solution exists with `\l` (not using HTML label):

```
digraph TTS {
    node [shape="box"];
    a [label="line 1 --------\lline 2 ----\lline3\l"];
}
```

Comment: The `\l` notation is definitely the nicest solution for the problem as described. The reason I'm using HTML is because I want parts of the labels to be in italics, and possibly other forms of fine-grained control that only HTML seems to offer.